# Package file is invalid when trying to load Facebook

Tags: facebook, system-error

When I try to load the Facebook app on my new Samsung Galaxy S3, I get an error of `Package File is Invalid`. I have been able to load other apps via Google Play store. Facebook seems to be the only one I'm having trouble with.

Comment: Hi, this has been fixed by Google already, as I updated in my Answer. Please upvote one of the answers and accept it so that this can be closed already. :)

Answer (score 2):

This error has been [noticed recently](http://www.droid-life.com/2013/08/08/play-store-update-to-4-3-10-causing-package-file-is-invalid-error-for-many-during-app-updates/). The other day, I was trying to update the `Samsung Push` app, but it kept on failing. So, I just kept trying to update it, despite the frustrations. Eventually, it updated successfully.

Maybe it's just a Google Play issue.

**Update 2013-08-13:** From Al's comments, Google has officially recognized this issue, as is in fact [listed in Google Support](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/3300875).

> We’ve received reports that some users are getting "Package File
>   Invalid" while trying to download or update apps.
>
> We’re currently investigating a permanent solution, and there are no
>   workarounds at this time.
>
> We’ll continue to update this page with developments, so check back
>   soon.

**EDIT #1:** Oops, looks like my UPDATE has been mentioned in bmdixon's answer already.

**UPDATE 2013-08-15:** As of this time, Google has already fixed the issue. [Source](http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/08/14/play-store-team-acknowledges-pervasive-package-file-invalid-error-when-installing-or-updating-apps-no-fix-yet/).

Comment: See also: http://phandroid.com/2013/08/13/package-file-invalid-google-play-store/

Comment: @AlEverett Thanks! Added your comment to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Play Store issue. It has been [acknowledged](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/3300875) by Google and they are looking at it. There is no fix or workaround at the moment.